# How to pass a function as parameter in class(C++)

Tags: c++, class

I am doing Sort a List Of Student via:
1.Via Name
2.Via Date Of Birth
Both only differ type of compare,the rest is the same.
Because I do not want duplicate code I have used template type to do this:

```
class Student
{
    Date date;  // Date is a class
    Name name;  // Name is a class
   public:
    Date getDate() { return date; }
    Name getName() { return name; }
};
class ListOfStudent
{
    vector<Student> List;

   public:
    bool CompareDate(Date &d1, Date &d2);  // define d1<d2
    bool CompareName(Name &n1, Name &n2);  // define n1<n2

    void SortViaName()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); ++i)
            int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < List.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (CompareName(List[j].getName(), List[min].getName()))
                min = j;
        }
        if (min != i)
            swap(List[i], List[min]);
    }

    void SortViaDate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); ++i)
            int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < List.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (CompareName(List[j].getDate(), List[min].getDate()))
                min = j;
        }
        if (min != i)
            swap(List[i], List[min]);
    }

    // Because i do not want to duplicate code so I do:
    template <typename T>
    void Sort(bool (*f)(T, T), T (*t)())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); ++i)
            int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < List.size(); ++j)
        {
            if ((*f)(DS[j].(*t)(), List[i].(*t)()))
                min = j;
        }
        if (min != i)
            swap(List[i], List[min]);
    }
};
```

It has  something wrong at template function so I need your supports.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make things generic, the simplest way to set things up is to make the `CompareThing` function optionally take a `Student&` instead of a `Date` or `Name`.

**Note:** `CompareDate` and `CompareName` should be **either static or global**, that way you can pass them around as function pointers.

```
// We'll keep these
// Also they should either be static or global
bool CompareDate(Date &d1,Date &d2); //define d1<d2
bool CompareName(Name &n1,Name &n2); //define n1<n2

// Because these can both be used with Student, it's easy to template over them
bool CompareDate(Student &s1, Student &s2) {
    return CompareDate(s1.getDate(), s2.getDate()); 
}
bool CompareName(Student &s1, Student &s2) {
    return CompareName(s1.getName(), s2.getName()); 
}
```

Then, we can write `Sort` like this:

```
void Sort(bool(*compare)(Student&, Student&)) {
    std::sort(List.begin(), List.end(), compare); 
}
void SortViaName() {
    Sort(CompareName); 
}
void SortViaDate() {
    Sort(CompareDate); 
}
```

#### Using your selection sort

We can write `Sort` to take the function as a parameter, and then use your selection sort instead of `std::sort`:

```
void Sort(bool (*compare)(Student&, Student&))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); ++i) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < List.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (compare(List[j].getName(), List[min].getName()))
                min = j;
        }
        if (min != i)
            swap(List[i], List[min]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I mean is working with select sort not std::sort and how to create a function competition with both CompareDate and CompareName via Select Sort

Comment: I updated the answer. Is there any reason you don't want to use `std::sort`?

Comment: when I call Sort(CompareViaDate)or Sort(CompareViaName) compiler display error: no matching function for call to ListOfStudent::Sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'|.

Comment: Are you still declaring them as member functions?

Comment: yeah,all of them is member functions in ListOfStudent class

Comment: It's not possible to convert a member function to a function pointer. Member functions require an object to be called with. You have to either make them static functions or global functions. Or, alternatively, we could use lambdas